# Displayport MST, secondary monitor stuck in sleep-mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 19.10 LTS with a GeForce GTX 970.
I have two Dell monitors U2515H and a U2713HM, the 27" is setup as primary monitor.
The connection is PC->U2515H->U2713HM, with DP1.2 enabled on the 25"

Previously, I had issues where my secondary display would go into sleep mode, but following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854754/monitor-stays-in-sleep-when-daisy-chained-via-displayport) answer fixed my issues.

After upgrading to the newest nvidia driver(440) I am now facing the same issues.
The secondary monitor always go into sleep-mode. If I change which monitor is the primary, the secondary is always the one to be stuck in sleep-mode.

I have tried using `xrandr` as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131558/second-external-monitor-not-waking-up) answer, but to no avail.
I have not been able to find any other useful suggestions.

Ubuntu: 19.10 LTS
Kernel: 5.5.9
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
GPU: GeForce GTX 970, nvidia driver 440.64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In your X-configuration file (should be `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) add a Device-Option "HardDPMS", set to "false".

In my case, the Device-Section looks like:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2060"
    Option         "HardDPMS"  "false"
EndSection
```

You will need your other work-around (`xset dpms force off`) as well.

(Hints on the modified driver behaviour were found [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250696))

Comment: Thank you! Finally got it working. Added "HARDDPMS" and fixed some other configs in `xorg.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Leu's solution works like a charm, but for those who do not have a "xorg.conf" in above location (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) - there is simple option to generate one based on your current configuration.

Simply open

`"NVIDIA X Server Settings" -> "X Server Display Configuration" -> "Save to X Configuration File"`

(bottom right button).